# Как обращаться к сообществу?

Tags: филозабавы, грамотная-речь

В вопросе о гиперболе появился ответ, подписанный "Сообщество ХэшКод". У меня возник уточняющий вопрос, и я засомневался, как обратиться к автору ответа:

1. Уважаемое Сообщество, не могло бы ты дать ссылку на первоисточник?
2. Уважаемое Сообщество, не могли бы вы дать ссылку?..

Мне не нравится ни один из вариантов, в обоих чувствуется какая-то натяжка. Возможен ли здесь вообще правильный вариант, или ну его совсем, это обращение?..

Answer (score 1):

Сообщество подразумевает как минимум двух членов. Может, "уважаемые члены Сообщества, не могли бы вы..."

Answer (score 1):

Вся фишка-то в том, что от имени сообщества пишет один человек. Ну допустим, что разные посты могут писать разные люди (хотя, похоже, это не наш случай), но конкретный-то пост - точно один.

ЗЫ Я бы к нему обращался Ваше Высокопреосвященство.

Comment: длинновато. Я бы сократил до ВВ. Или даже сразу до ВВП.

Comment: Это уж как Вам ближе.

Answer (score 0):

Предпочтительнее вариант без прямого обращения к Сообществу через местоимение, т. е. обойти пп. 1 и 2. "Уважаемое Сообщество, мне хотелось бы...". Ну, а если обязательно надо выбрать из двух зол меньшее, то, на мой взгляд, это п. 2